# HeaderTemplate with multiple items

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, styles

I'm trying to write a `HeaderTemplate` for an extender. So far, I've noticed all the examples use the `{Binding}` keyword to get the data from the header. However, what happens if there are multiple controls within the Header? How do I specify that those controls should be inserted at a specific location?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- what do I put in here? -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Expander Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}">
    <Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>Some Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeBinding}" />
            <Button />
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Image Source="https://www.google.com/logos/2012/steno12-hp.jpg" />
</Expander>
```

Should I be moving my binding into the `HeaderTemplate` in the style and just overwriting whatever the `Header` in the `Expander` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ContentPresenter` to insert whatever the usual content would be into your Template

For example:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. Except that I ended up giving my bindings names and then in the DataTemplate changing them to be `{Binding ElementName=NameIGave, Path=Text}`. That way I could style those appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Header's property Content could contain only one object.

If you merge these object in one panel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Some Text</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeBinding}" />
    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

then in template you could use {binding}

Comment: Right, that was an error in my post. They are in a panel in the Expander.Header element. What structure does the `{Binding}` tag go into?

Comment: `{Binding}` goes to item's DataContext. In this case it would be StackPanel.

Comment: Could you please include what code would go into the "<!-- what do I put in here? -->".

Comment: You may put something like this:
       `<Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Red">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>`

Comment: But is there any reason to use DataTemplate? If you delete this property you would see control that you specified in header property.