# Expander full window height

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Firstly, I am new to WPF design. Anyway, I have an expander containing a listbox located at the bottom of my window. When the expander is minimized I want the first two elements in the listbox to be visible but when it is maximized I want it to take up the full screen height. I am unsure about how to go about this and would really appreciate any hints. Below is the code I have to deal with this so far.

```
            <Window x:Class="WPFPlay.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" SizeToContent="Manual">
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Border Name="ContentBorder" Width="0">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Border Name="ContentBorder" Width="0">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Name="B1" Content="+" Click="B1_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Expander Name="MainExpander1" Template="{StaticResource VerticalExpander}" IsExpanded="False">
                        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label Content="Document1"/>
                                <Label Content="Document2"/>
                                <Label Content="Document3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Expander>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock FontSize="14">
            <Bold>
                <Run>
                    Header + Labels etc
                </Run>
            </Bold>
            </TextBlock>
        </WrapPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Expander VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="StatusBarExpander" ExpandDirection="Up" IsExpanded="False">
                <StackPanel>
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" />
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Button Content="button1"/>
            <Button Content="button2"/>
            <Button Content="button3"/>
            <Button Content="button4"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <!-- Centre of it all!!!-->
        <ContentControl />
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, Swtting the Expander.VerticalAlignment to Stretch will do the trick.

As for your first question. The Expander control inherit from HeaderedContentControl which means it has Header property which you can customize.
You can do this by setting the HeaderTemplate to another list box which will show only the first  two elements.

[Similar question in Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821861/headertemplate-with-multiple-items)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried setting the VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment to stretch but the expander does not stretch to the full screen height. It goes no higher than the bottom of the ContentControl I have in the centre of the screen. There are dock panel on the left, right and top of the screen also.

Comment: Maybe you can post your full xaml here so Ican exmine it better.

Comment: Full xaml posted above as requested. Many thanks. Note: B1_Click is in the code behind and it simply hides or shows the expander in the right dock panel.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked on this and it seems that you will have to add another seperation in a grid level. (2 rows - Auto and Star) which will contains the DockPanel and Bottom expander repectivly.